# Word coocurrence in word2vec

Tags: word2vec

Based on the vector values of two words in word2vec, could we judge whether they co-occur and frequencies of coocurrence?

Answer (score 0):

Let the two words be $a,b$ and let $u_a,v_b$ be the respective in/out representation vectors of each word (usually word2vec retains only the in representation, but both are needed for training). Then the probability of co-occurance within the training window size should be:

$$\frac{\exp(u_a\cdot v_b)}{\sum_i \exp(u_a\cdot v_i)}$$,

Where the sum is over your vocabulary.

Comment: Thanks, but what I mean is two `in` representation of two distinct words, does the usage of vector similarity measure like consine similarity helps in determine the concurrence of two words?

Comment: @william007: No. it doesn’t make sense to measure co-occurrence with the same representation. Words are similar if they are used in similar contexts, but that doesn’t imply they co-occur